# How to display and rebind data (not for editing) to ViewModel in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using a custom ViewModel in the following general manner:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        // Attempt to fetch object from DB
        var obj = Repository.GetObject(id);

        // Populate Dto
        var viewModel = new ObjectViewModel();
        var adapter = new ObjectAdapter(obj, viewModel, da);
        adapter.MapDto();

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(int id, ObjectViewModel viewModel)
    {
        // Fetch object from DB
        var obj = Repository.GetObject(id);

        // Update object from DTO
        var adapter = new ObjectAdapter(obj, viewModel, da);
        adapter.MapObject();

        // Save back to DB
        Repository.SaveChanges();

        // Return to the Index
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

...

So then on my view, I want to display a bit of data but not for editing.  At present I've tried:

```
<%: Model.Data %>
```

And I've tried a Html.Label().  They both display the data fine.

But the problem is this.  On POST action, the "<%: Model.Data %>" or the label don't bind back to the ViewModel.  So "MapObject()" will map null for "Model.Data" on the POST action.

I'm hoping (expecting) there's a simple solution here?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a hidden field:

```
Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Data)
```

If you only write the value to the page with `<%: Model.Data %>` it won't get included when the form is submitted.  The hidden field will submit with the form but, obviously, not be visible to the user.

Answer (score 0):

What if you tried using the Html.LabelFor(x => x.Data)

UPDATED: Changed the Lambda expression from model to x.

Comment: Using the syntax <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.Data) %>, strangely the view renders the property name (i.e. "Data") instead of the value.  Yet, this seems to be the right syntax?  (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/10/asp-net-mvc-2-strongly-typed-html-helpers.aspx)

Comment: Try it like this:  <%= Html.LabelFor(x => x.Data) %>

Comment: Unfortunately, same result.  The "Data" is simply a string in this case (FYI).

Comment: I've accepted Jon's answer (works nicely).  Thanks for your help in any case, Robert.  Cheers!